How to get two independent overview layouts in Blender?
I want to work with two models in one .blend file at the same time. For example, I have 2 cubes with different materials and I want to see both of materials at the same time:

I've tried to create a new window and select different cubes, but without any results - I see the same shader in both windows. What can I do (except of opening the new blender application - my pc won't be able to handle it and I'm not even sure windows will let me open the same file twice)?

One way around this is to have two instances of Blender open simultaneously with each of the two shaders active in one of the program instance's Shading Workspaces, and then either Alt-Tab between them, or, unmaximize each window and position it to occupy one half of the screen so that both materials can be seen at once. For smaller projects, this won't likely lead to a lot of performance overhead.

@R-800 that looks like a complete answer, and I think it’s the only way to do this. I recommend you post it as such.

You can pin active material using pin icon:

Select one object, press on pin icon:

Then select other one and press pin icon in second widow.

Yes, it works! Thank you!
